# FullCalendar show only weekDays

Tags: jquery, date, calendar, fullcalendar, timetable

Hello guys I'm trying to show a week timetable, I must show only the name of the date, without date. Such as time table in agenda view.
User must be able to select a range in day of the week.
For example John Doe Monday from 15:00 to 18:00, Martin Friday from 9:00 to 15:00, and so...

I just try to create my personal view as "settimana" like this:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
   header: {
       left:'',
       center:'',
       right:'',
    }, 
    editable: true,
    views: {
        settimana:{
            type:'agendaWeek',
            duration: { days: 7 },
            title: 'Apertura',
        }
    },
    defaultView: 'settimana',
});
```

How can I do it? What I must set in option when calling jQuery fullCalendar plugin?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This shows only Monday - Friday http://jsfiddle.net/w11xw5gt/1/

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: '',
        center: '',
        right: '',
    },
    editable: true,
    views: {
        settimana: {
            type: 'agendaWeek',
            duration: {
                days: 7
            },
            title: 'Apertura',
            columnFormat: 'dddd', // Format the day to only show like 'Monday'
            hiddenDays: [0, 6] // Hide Sunday and Saturday?
        }
    },
    defaultView: 'settimana',
});
```

See [Info for display options](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/) and [text/time customization](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/text/)