# Restrict saturday and sundays in html5 date type

Tags: jquery, html

I am looking for `weekend dates restriction` in html5 `input type=date`.
I found this using datapicker 

http://jsfiddle.net/rLnTQ/876/

But I don't want using date picker I want using `input type=date` only

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="date" id="days">
```

Any ideas please??

Comment: You can't in restrict day html but you can make a javascript verification..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FullCalendar show only weekDays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33673487/fullcalendar-show-only-weekdays)