# FullCalendar week view start on Monday

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I want to do something similar to this: [show only weekdays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33673487/fullcalendar-show-only-weekdays), however, I would like it to start on the first day of the week (or show from Sunday to the next Saturday).

I have tried setting a moment for the `start` and `intervalStart` option of the first day of the week (i.e. Sunday) but this doesn't seem to work.

Edit ***(from link above)***:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: '',
        center: '',
        right: '',
    },
    editable: true,
    views: {
        settimana: {
            type: 'agendaWeek',
            duration: {
                days: 7
            },
            title: 'Apertura',
            columnFormat: 'dddd', // Format the day to only show like 'Monday'
            hiddenDays: [0, 6] // Hide Sunday and Saturday?
        }
    },
    defaultView: 'settimana',
    });
```

Comment: You need to provide the code you are having problems with, we can't help otherwise

Comment: what about just using https://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/firstDay/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to do this with:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    ...  
    // Added the default date
    defaultDate: $.fullCalendar.moment().startOf('week'),
    ...
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

For future reference, for **custom views** the [dateAlignment](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/dateAlignment) option can be used to implement something like *weekdaysOnlyView*.

Answer (score 1):

You can add firstDay: 1.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  firstDay: 1,
})
```

or

```
let calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
 firstDay: 1,
 ...
});
```